# fix image position when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I have an image with a position fixed in a page. When I re-size the browser the image get over my page content how can i prevent that to happen ?

```
<div >
  <img id="img1" class="wrapperImage"></img>
</div>

 <style type="text/css">
   .wrapperImage
   {
   position : fixed;
   width:200px;
   height:100px
   }
  </style>
```

Comment: `position:fixed` is the prob, you would need to use `float` property with correct widths set(in %) so that this aligns well or adjusts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to set a central div and set for it `position:relative` and set for you image 
`position:absolute` that in your central div and with `z-index` you can change element priority that you want to show,then you set `z-index:10` for your image.

Answer (score 1):

```
   .wrapperImage {
       position : fixed;
       width: 100%;
       max-width:200px;
       height:auto
   }
```

Sizes in percentage improves your [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscocarvalho/85AZn/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding `z-index:-1;` to your css.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, the image would remain in the same position even when you resize the window,

By giving the parent tag relative positioning, and the child tad absolute, the position won't change even when the window is resized

```
<div id="divname">
  <img id="img1" class="wrapperImage"></img>
</div>

 <style type="text/css">
   .divname{
      position:relative; 
   }

   .wrapperImage
   {
     position : absolute;
     z-index:-1;  //depending weather your image should appear 
                       at the above or below div change it to +1 or -1
     top: 100px;
     right: 100px; 
     width:200px;
     height:100px
   }
  </style>
```